# Javafx Can not run on Debian8 Arm Device NanoPC T3

Tags: java, linux, javafx, arm, debian

**My target**

I want to run javafx on Linux Arm device, but failed!

**NanoPC T3, there are some information:**

```
fa@NanoPi3:~$ uname -a
Linux NanoPi3 3.4.39-s5p6818 #3 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 19 18:28:53 HKT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

fa@NanoPi3:~$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l

fa@NanoPi3:~$ getconf LONG_BIT
32

Display: 7 in Capacitive screen (X710）
```

**I had done：**

1. Download jdk-8u144-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz
2. Download [JavaFX Embedded SDK](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/get/)
3. Copy the files according [javafxports](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#anchor-1)
4. Write a sample app and package, run on my NanoPC T3:

   ```
   public class Main extends Application {
       @Override
       public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
           try {
               StackPane root = new StackPane();

               Button btn = new Button();
               btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
               btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                   @Override
                   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                       System.out.println("Hello World!");
                   }
               });
               root.getChildren().add(btn);

               Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
               scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

               primaryStage.setScene(scene);
               primaryStage.setTitle("Hello ARM");
               primaryStage.show();
           } catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           launch(args);
       }
   }
   ```

**My problem**

When I run the app by cammond: java -jar HelloArm.jar, system UI is not RESPONSABLE.
But, I log in the device using ssh normally,  also can see the thread java program:

```
ps -aux | grep java.
```

When I kill it, System UI get right again. I test adding some flag for java ([tips from here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Monocle)):

```
-Dmonocle.platform=Monocle -Djavafx.debug=true -Dprism.order=sw
```

**Some idea**

1. I test Java swing, it is OK
2. I found that Javafx using monocle on linux. I don't know, X11 is uncorret for javafx? Or, I must be installed some thing for X11?

Comment: I've run JavaFX 8 successfully on a UDOO Quad (ARMv7). It wasn't easy, most important thing is that JavaFX will use the frambebuffer /dev/fb0.

Comment: Thanks! M. le Rutte yesterday .  I found that must use fb options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, We found that we need to add `-Djavafx.platform = eglfb`, let the `JavaFX` rander the UI using `eglfb`.

Good luck.

Thanks.